# How to change a tibble of lists to normal columns and preserve the column names

Tags: r, list, tidyr, unnest

I have the following data:

```
dat <- structure(list(description = list("MedianTime_SpeederTemp", "MedianTime_SpeederTemp"),
                      variables   = list(list(src = "y", shown = TRUE),
                                         list(src = "x", shown = FALSE)),
                      id          = list(13190L, 14190L)),
                 row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  description variables        id       
  <list>      <list>           <list>   
1 <chr [1]>   <named list [2]> <int [1]>
2 <chr [1]>   <named list [2]> <int [1]>
```

As you can see the data contains three list columns. The second list column is a nested list.

So what I want to do now is:

1. unnest the second column "variables" which I know I can do with

   `dat %>% unnest_wider(variables)`
2. Unlist the other two columns so that they contain the "true" data format, i.e. the character string for "description" and the number stored in "id" while preserving the column names. And here I struggle. I also tried `unnest_wider` on the "description column, but it changed the column name to "...1", but I want to keep it as "description". I know I could probably manually change this afterwards, but my real data has hundreds of these columns, so that's not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't just using `unnest` work?

Comment: Ok, sometimes it's easier than expected. Didn't thought that this would work and didn't try for that reason. Thanks for the solution!